# Add materialRoute at the ontap function

Tags: flutter

I try to open another page that I design on flutter but I get an error at the end of the code , at the brackets ( at the `onTap(){}`) what should I add in the brackets next to the `ElementPageDetail`? And also , why can't I add another `container` in the `SingleChildScrollView` that I created? It's because of the `Stack`? `Expanded`?

```
class _ElementMainPageState extends State<ElementMainPage> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7);
  double _indicatorHeight = 35.45;
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  List<String> _heroTag = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
  List<String> _heroTextTag = List.generate(10, (index) => "t$index");

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Expanded(
                        flex: 8,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Positioned(
                              left: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              bottom: 160,
                              top: 0,
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (_) =>
                                                    ElementDetailPage()));
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 24),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                  color: Colors.black
                                                      .withOpacity(0.2),
                                                  spreadRadius: -4,
                                                  blurRadius: 4,
                                                  offset: Offset(-4, 24))
                                            ],
                                            color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: NetworkImage(
                                                    "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f9/54/87/f95487ddee97d480f621aa27fc924443.jpg"),
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Spacer(),
                                            Container(
                                              height: 48,
                                              width: 48,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white
                                                      .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "20",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 18),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 8,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "questions to adress",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "Unknown Stage",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 24,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ))
```

And the ElementDetailPage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ElementDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String imageTag;

  String titleTag;

  ElementDetailPage(this.imageTag, this.titleTag);

  @override
  _ElementDetailPageState createState() => _ElementDetailPageState();
}

class _ElementDetailPageState extends State<ElementDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Hero(
                tag: widget.imageTag,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f9/54/87/f95487ddee97d480f621aa27fc924443.jpg"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 64,
                            width: 64,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "20",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "questions to adress",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Unknown stage",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 64,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ""
                        "Unknown stage is the first fase to know somebody new."
                        " It is the easiest stage to see if you like the person in front of you "
                        "and if you want to continue forming a bound with them to become friends or"
                        "\n if there aren't your type of a person and let them go.This question will have some "
                        " basic questions and some intimate questions, if somebody wants to skip a question i propose a shot"
                        " \n WARNING : You may fall in love",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: 16,
              top: 32,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )),
          Positioned(
              top: 600,
              left: 100,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white30],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Start playing",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              top: 700,
              left: 100,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black87],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Spotify Playlist",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/k4IxdPl

Answer (score 0):

In _ElementMainPageState() --> Wrap the Expanded widget inside the MaterialApp -> Scaffold Widget to resolve the navigating issue

And main thing is ElementDetailPage() too warp with Scaffold widget

Comment: I get an error because Scaffold(child:Expanded - child gives error

Comment: Yes, if we load the Expanded widget direct child to scaffold it will throw a error. Instead of expanded widget please replace the container widget

Answer (score 0):

For the error showed up in this error message:
[image]

In your ElementDetailPage, you are setting 2 positional arguments. By definition, these arguments need to be provided when you create a new `ElementDetailPage`.

To answer your question, you need to put the value of imageTag and titleTag, within the bracket. If you don't want to make these arguments compulsory, you can define them as optional parameters by putting them in the curly bracket:

```dart
class ElementDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String imageTag;

  String titleTag;

  ElementDetailPage({this.imageTag, this.titleTag});

  @override
  _ElementDetailPageState createState() => _ElementDetailPageState();
}
```

Comment: it gives me a red screen

Comment: @megatronn2 make sure both of the `imageTag` and `titleTag` that you passed in the `ElementDetailPage(imageTag, titleTag)` must be `not null`;